# Java Calendar: 1am switchover to standard time (from DST)

Tags: java, calendar

I have some code that uses Calendar.set() to return the beginning of the hour for a given date value. I encountered the following issue on Sunday Nov 4th, 2012 (Eastern Timezone - EDT to EST switchover):

```
public void testStartOfHourDST1() {
    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    long time = 1352005200000L; // Nov 4, 2012, 1AM EDT
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
        
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    System.out.println(new Date(time));
    System.out.println(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
            
    assertEquals(cal.getTimeInMillis(), time); // fails
    
    return;
}
```

Ouput:

> Sun Nov 04 01:00:00 EDT 2012
>
> Sun Nov 04 01:00:00 EST 2012
>
> 1.6.0_35

Perhaps this is not the correct way to be using calendar, but running the same test for the next hour (or previous hour) works fine. Is this a JVM issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really an issue, in the sense that it is deterministic and doing what it was programmed to do.  It's an issue if you would prefer that it pick the earlier of the two 1ams!

After changing fields on the Calendar the only information it has is "1am in US/Eastern".  Well, your timezone had two 1ams that day, which one is it supposed to pick?  The authors of OpenJDK made a decision that when presented with this ambiguity, they would always interpret it as the later one, in standard time.  This comment is from java.util.GregorianCalendar OpenJDK 6:

> ```
>     // 2. The transition out of DST.  Here, a designated time of 1:00 am - 1:59 am
>     //    can be in standard or DST.  Both are valid representations (the rep
>     //    jumps from 1:59:59 DST to 1:00:00 Std).
>     //    Again, we assume standard time.
> ```

If you print out the actual values of the numbers you will see `cal.getTimeInMillis()` has actually been changed by an hour from the value of `time`.

Comment: Good point. So it seems Calendar does not support a way to disambiguate these two overlapping hours (except by using setTime/setTimeInMillis -- or by using setTimeZone as mentioned by @Nambari.

Comment: Is the calendar using the _most recent time_ or is it applying the default timezone at the time the Calendar is created (which would be EST if the program is being run after the daylight saving time switch has occurred)... I don't know the answer.

Comment: @jahroy The comments in the code for java.util.GregorianCalendar indicate that it will always interpret 1:00-1:59 of that day as being in standard time, rather than daylight savings as a matter of arbitrary convention. " ... Here, a designated time of 1:00 am - 1:59 am can be in standard or DST.  Both are valid representations (the rep jumps from 1:59:59 DST to 1:00:00 Std). Again, we assume standard time."

Answer (score 0):

Getting the correct time zone is very important. For example, as I'm sure you are aware the system current time in milliseconds is measured from midnight on the 1st of January 1970. This is well documented. The Date constructor JavaDoc says:

> **public Date(long date)**
>
> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

which is fine, but makes the output of this program a little hard to understand at first:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
        Date d = new Date(-3600000);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        System.out.println(String.format("%8dms -> %s",
                    Long.valueOf(d.getTime()) ,df.format(d)));

        d.setTime(0);
        System.out.println(String.format("%8dms -> %s",
                    Long.valueOf(d.getTime()) ,df.format(d)));
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
-3600000ms -> January 01, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT
       0ms -> January 01, 1970 01:00:00.000 GMT
```

As you can see, the epoch is apparently displaced by an hour!

Except it is not. If you use the "GMT" time zone explicitly, all is well. The "Europe/London" time zone is simply tricky like that.

When working with Calendars, understand the time zone you are using or be caught out.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this example is a bit confusing because the date formatting prints 'GMT' for different timezones.  If you use the 'Z' output format it will show +0100 (which is clear). So the problem with your example is not that Europe/London is 'tricky', but just that the string output is ambiguous. My mistake was not realizing that the set() functions would cause Calendar to re-evaluate its UTC time from scratch (and thus suffer the confusion between having to figure out which '1am' to use). The original problem only occurs with timezones that support DST offset.